# Kernel and cokernel of sheaves of rings over a topological space

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\phi:F\to G$ be a morphism of presheaves of rings over a topological space $X$. One can define $Ker(\phi)$ and $Coker(\phi)$.

Since $F,G$ are presheaves of rings, for each open $U\subset X$, $Ker(\phi)(U)$ is not a unital ring but rather a module of $F(U)$. For $Coker(\phi)(U)$, I have it as a quotient module of $G(U)$ which is a module over $F(U)$ at best. They are not rings?

What is the meaning of $Ker(\phi),Coker(\phi)$ in the case of morphism of presheave of rings here? If they are presheaves of abelian category objects, it would make sense for some time.

Comment: $\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$ is a presheaf of ideals of $F$, which could be also viewed as a presheaf of abelian groups or a presheaf of $F$-modules.  I don't see the issue with $\operatorname{coker}(\phi)$ - it's a presheaf of rings (and also a presheaf of $G$-algebras).

Comment: @DanielSchepler The thing makes me worrying is that $Coker(\phi)$ is a quotient of rings. What is the meaning of quotient of rings here?

Comment: Oh, right, of course... the best you could do would be to view $\phi$ as a morphism of presheaves of $F$-modules, or as a morphism of presheaves of abelian groups.  And the cokernel of that map is not something I've often seen considered.

Comment: @DanielSchepler So it is not natural to consider morphism of sheaf of rings but to consider morphism of sheaf of modules associated with their sheaf of rings. So I am still trying to work over the sheaf of objects sitting in abelian category instead of non-abelian and the latter is bad. Is this the reason that one consider morphism of sheaf of modules associated with their sheaf of rings?

Comment: I wonder if, by "ring", your source doesn't mean unital rings.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes. The ring may not be unital ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the target category is not the usual one of unital rings, but instead the category of (possibly) nonunital rings; i.e. associative $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras.

This category has a zero object, so the (co)kernel of a map is defined as the (co)equalizer of that map with the parallel zero map.

Limits of presheaves are given pointwise, so $\ker(\phi)(U)$ is the kernel of $F(U) \to G(U)$, and similarly for the cokernel.

Comment: Just to confirm, Hartshorne means the category of rings includes non-unital rings? If this is the case, why do people bother to study sheaf of modules with its associated sheaf of rings rather than study the category of  rings including non-unital rings?

Comment: @user45765: IIRC, Hartshorne's algebraic geometry book uses "ring" to mean a commutative ring with unity.